# Install Ubuntu 14 onto Portable Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, toshiba, portable

My system:
OS: Windows 8.1
Brand: Toshiba Satellite P55t-A
RAM: 8Gb
CPU:2.30 Ghz
HHD: 618Gb Free Space

Portable HD: 2TB Free Space
Toshiba Canvio Hard Drive.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 14 on to  my Portable Hard Drive? If so could you list either a link or the steps to do it. I have it burn on a DVD, when I insert the DVD into my laptop and boot from it. It gives me 3 options, Install, OEM Install and one more I can't remember. I think it was "try" or something.  When I clicked on  Install it just started to install. Not sure if that is what's suppose to happen then it gives me the option?
If you need any other information  just let me know. jjgremo@gmail.com
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, does your system use UEFI or Bios? A quick way to check is to right click on my computer in Windows 8, select manage, disk management. 
If it reports a 100 mb system reserved partition you are likely using Bios. You can also boot up the UEFI configuration utility and check there (check your laptop key combination online, usually one of the function keys or del/ esc)

If it is a new laptop that came with Windows 8 it is almost guaranteed to be set up in UEFI mode with secure boot enabled. I am assuming that it is using UEFI.

Installing to an external drive will be quite slow, you are better off installing in a virtual machine (use virtual box). Usually it is easier to disable secure boot to install, however it should work with secure boot enabled.

if you still want to install to a secondary hdd  perform these steps:

1-Create a full disk backup of your Windows 8 system (system image)+a repair disk. If you wipe your system by mistake you can always restore. Create system recovery disks also . Note if you make a partitioning mistake you can hose your Windows install completely - you will need to save the system image to another drive/set of dvds.

2-Boot up the Ubuntu live cd, click install and choose "something else"

3 - you should see a list of disks that Ubuntu has detected . Select your external drive and partition it as follows(assuming you want your Windows 8 and Ubuntu to be completely separate from each other)

Create a 1 GB partition named EFIboot. 
Create another partition with a swap mount point and give it a couple of GB. (4GB should do, or equal your ram) 
Create a third partition (remaining space using ext4 with a / mount point.

. At the bottom of the installation screen it will prompt you for the bootloader location - choose your external disk (usually /dev/sdb).

When you need to boot Ubuntu simply plug in the hdd into a USB port and choose boot from USB in UEFI . For booting Windows 8 simply remove the hdd and Windows 8 should boot normally.

If your system is using the standard Bios/mbr setup , the steps are identical, but you won't need to create a EFIboot partition when installing.